# Is there any way to open SQL Editor which can only query statements of type just "read only" in DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, production-environment, dbeaver

I am a Junior Software engineer and recently got access to Production DB. The creds I got are of Admin. I am afraid that I will unintentionally make unknown changes in Prod DB.
So I want to know if we can create a SQL editor which can only do "Select" statement.
And will not query any other type of statements.
We use DBeaver IDE.

I could not find much resources online on this issue.

Comment: As an admin you should be able to create your own read-only account. Or set the permissions for your current account to read-only

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with your client, but you can change the user in the database:

```
ALTER ROLE your_user SET default_transaction_read_only = on;
```

You can explicitly change the setting with the `SET` statement in your current database session.